# Is there any API that can verify the email validity?

Tags: api, validation, email-validation

So What I have noticed is that some website does not have to send me a mail to tell if my email adress if valid or not, I mean if I use "hjdfjh@jhf.com" it won't be considered as a valid email adress because it does not exist, it is not a gmail account or outlook or whatever, and this can be checked without sending a mail ( having a clickable link to activate the account ), and that's what I want to have in my application, I don't want to send a mail to my users at all.

Of course I checked if the email adress is valid ( syntax ) but obviously it is not enough at all, is there any api that can do that for me or us ( people interested by such API ).

I don't think I have to share any code because all the code is wotking fine for me, but I need an idea.

Any help would be much apreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to improve upon regex validation is to parse the domain out of the email address and perform a DNS MX lookup to validate that the domain exists and can receive mail. This will reject some addresses which are are relying on a fallback to the domain's A record -- but many mail servers will reject mail from these domains for the same reason, so it's unlikely that a legitimate domain will be rejected.

(As an aside, this method would **not** reject `hjdfjh@hjf.com`, because `jhf.com` has a valid MX record, making this an entirely plausible email address.)

There exist many commercial APIs that can perform a deeper validation of email addresses, up to the point of connecting to the mail server and asking it to validate the address. Recommending one of those APIs is beyond the scope of this site.